# Can \items be made indented all the way down?

Tags: lists, indentation, itemize

Can `\item`s be made indented all the way down?

Using the standard `itemize` environmnet, and a `\hspace` the first line gets indented. However, if the bullet point is on more than one line, it looks a bit strange to me because the rest the other lines are not indented:

```
\begin{itemize}
\large{\item \hspace{0.3cm} Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}\vspace{0.4cm}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the "of" and "field" vertically aligned with "It" in my example?

Comment: The screenshot you provide does not seem to be representative of what LaTeX's `\itemize` environment would usually generate. Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example) that gives rise to the problem you're trying to fix. In particular, please be sure to point out where you place the `\hspace` command.

Comment: If you want to increase the space between the bullet and the text, you could use `enumitem` to change the list appearance, instead of adding `\hspace` manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)'s key-value interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}% Default
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth-\labelsep+\leftmargin,labelsep=20pt]
  \item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The indent is set using `labelsep=<len>` (specified in the above example as `20pt`), and compensated in terms of the left margin using a `\dimexpr` (expression in dimensions). Other options (depending on your alignment requirements) are also available, of course. Peruse the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more details.